# Trying to open file explorer in java and save the selected file's path to a variable

Tags: java

I am making a program in java and I have a button setup that executes the following method:

```
baseFileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
                "explorer.exe",
                "/select," + "\"" + filePath + "\""
            });
        } catch (IOException exp) {
        }
    }
}
```

However, instead of being able to select the file, it instead opens the file. What is the best way to be able to open the file explorer, select a file, and save that file's path into a variable?`enter code here`

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

Comment: I was trying to avoid file chooser as I do not like how they look. Is there a way I can use the windows file explorer to select a file and save its path?

Comment: To modify how it looks, check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) out. You can make it look like the file explorer popup/window. There are some code examples for how to do it on the page